# My 5-year daughter likes to play baby

Tags: pre-schooler

My daughter is 5 year old and she likes to play baby.

I don't mean she wet their pants or actually act like a baby. I mean she likes to immitate some baby talk and things like that. Completely manageable.

But I feel she's requesting more attention, maybe because in her mind, people care more about babies, so if she's a baby... I think you've got my point here.

At the same time, I'd like to promote some more independent behavior, like eating by herself, slicing the food by herself, getting a little more responsabilities, learning to be more patient, etc.

I know some of these things are hard even for grown-ups (such as being patient) but, well, someone has to help to start it from somewhere.

So I'd like to ask here: is this "baby playing" thing normal at this age? Should I care about it or is it part of a normal process? Do you also have experienced anything like that and how did you deal with it?

Comment: That seems normal. My 6/8 year olds sometimes do it too. With each other taking role of baby and parent in turns :)

Comment: @DVK I think we parents sometimes worry too much :-) thx

Comment: I totally agree with @DVK. Even my single-child daughter did that for a long time.  At 14 she still likes to be tucked in and I rather cherish that... one day she'll be "too old" for that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly normal.

Anecdotally, both my kids liked to play baby (and parent + baby when together :) well into kindergarten/preschool era. Here are more evidence: [{1}](http://parents.berkeley.edu/advice/preschoolaged/pretendingbaby.html); [{2}](http://www.mamapedia.com/article/annoying-baby-talk-from-my-toddler) or even [10YO](http://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/behaviour_development/1203878-8-yr-old-dd-talking-in-baby-voice-driving-me-mad-any-advice/AllOnOnePage) (or continues [into adulthood](http://www.askamanager.org/2013/05/how-to-get-an-employee-to-stop-using-baby-talk-in-the-office.html) :) Or the whole [gazillion Google links](https://www.google.com/search?q=preschooler%20play%20baby&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=preschooler%20%22talk%20like%20a%20baby%22&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&safe=off&start=10) :)

If you want to manage this, my best advice:

- Balance. Promise to play along with her "baby" stuff for every 4 hrs she does things like a more grown up child
- Offer to trade (you baby she adult) sometimes. It's MORE fun to playact to be a parent for many kids.
- If it's too much then simply refuse what is being asked in baby talk
- If still persists over the limits set by you, threaten to treat her like a real baby. NO tasty food (chocolate/cookies etc...). Just milk and fruit puree. Bedtime NOW. No TV/games. (and follow up on the threat)